# Why Increase in Money Supply Reduces Interest Rate in Money Market?

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate, money-supply, bonds, keynesian-economics

I understand the fact the Increase in Money Supply reduces the interest rate in Money Market.

**But these two explanations are confusing me a lot. I'm not able to understand which is correct.**

**Reason 1**

> **Let's Say Central Bank Increase Money Supply using Open Market Operation.** So, it will buy bonds > Bond Demand Up > Bond Price Up > Bond Interest Down > Money Demand Up till Ms = Md

**Reason 2**

> **Due to Increased Money Supply, People are holding more Money they wish in their Pockets.** They will use that extra money to Buy Bonds and then the same chain effects as above will follow.

Both the explanations are correct, as far as I think. **But which one is ultimately on work?**
Or are both working (2nd after 1st)?

Please help me in understanding. Thanks in Advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason 1 first and then reason 2.

Actually, central bank first decides a target interest rate and then moves the money through OMOs.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So it's like this? Say, initial int rate = 10. CB wants to target i = 5. With omo, say it comes down to 8 and by by public further down to 5. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, it works like this only

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally I am clear now after many days.